# Get BP FollowCamera Rotation and Location

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I'm accessing my FollowCamera https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXKjt.jpg from my BluePrintCharacter class in my C++ code, with this following line :

```
FollowCamera = GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UCameraComponent>();
FVector WorldLocationV = FollowCamera->GetWorldLocation();
```

But when I run my game, I get this error : **GetWorldLocation is not a member of UCameraComponent**

Why is this, and how can I get GetWorldLocation from FollowCamera in C++?

In BluePrint this seems to work fine : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCMcc.png

Comment: I think you should be casting your found component --- `FollowCamera = Cast<UCameraComponent>(FindComponentByClass<UCameraComponent>());

Answer (score 0):

According to the Unreal docs [UCameraComponent](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Camera/UCameraComponent/index.html) you are correct, GetWorldLocation isn't part of UCameraComponent.

Attached to the camera is a camera manager and to get the world location and rotation of the camera, you need to get this.

```
APlayerCameraManager *CameraManager = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->PlayerCameraManager;

FVector CameraLocation = CameraManager->GetCameraLocation();
FVector CameraForwardVector  = CameraManager->GetCameraRotation().Vector();
```

In case you need it, the #include is #include "Camera/PlayerCameraManager.h"

Comment: This is incorrect - GetWorldLocation is a member function of USceneComponent, which UCameraComponent derives from. Your approach for getting OP's desired output would work however